# How can we implement this without bash operator

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, test-kitchen

How can we change this bash operator with any resource

Just i am moving particular directories in to particular directories

```
bash " deploy" do
  cwd "#{stage}"
  code <<-EOH
    cp -pr "#{stage}/#{name}-#{package_version}.tar"  "#{stage_operator}/"
    tar xvf "#{stage}/#{name}-#{package_version}.tar"

    mv  #{stage}/processing/* #{scripts}/
    mv  #{stage}/config/* #{config}/
    mv  #{stage}/dags/*  #{dags}/
    mv  #{stage}/plugins/* #{ps}/
    mv  #{stage}/_lib/*  #{libs}/ 
 EOH
 not_if "ls -l \"#{stage_operator}\"|grep \"#{name}-#{package_version}.tar\" "
end
```

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write code for you? please refer [ask] and [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory plug (I wrote it) but the [`poise-archive`](https://github.com/poise/poise-archive) cookbook/resource probably covers what you need. Hard to tell precisely since you only showed a small snippet of the code.

On the other hand if what you have there works, probably just run with it.